# QGIS - keep square pixels in resampling

Tags: qgis, resampling, ascii, cell-size

I have a raster file (asc) with a resolution of about 10m, square pixels and an extent of X: 15929 Y: 16159. I am trying to resample this to a larger resolution (tried 20 and 30m). However, the output always has rectangular pixels with differing x and y values - not a big one, but it's there. For further use with a different software, I need the resampled file have square pixels (such that the header of the asc has the value "CELLSIZE" and not "dx" and "dy").
I have tried the raster calculator first, where you can only set the resolution by specifying the number of columns/rows. Since this didn't work I tried the GRASS tools r.resample and r.resamp.stats. In both, I set the extent to match the original file and then set the resolution to my desired value. I have also tried to not give an input for the extent but still, it gives non-square pixels.

Any advice on how to resolve this ?

Information on the original file:
Float 64 ASCII Grid (a DEM), dimensions:
[image]

Information on the output of r.resamp.stats:
Float64 Geotiff, dimensions:
[image]

Input given to r.resamp.stats:
[image]

Comment: You cannot generally keep the original extent with any pixel size. It is possible only when the extent is a multiple of the new pixel size. 100 m width is possible with 1 m and 2 m pixels, but not with 3 m pixel size.  Either the extent or the pixel size must be adjusted. However, you may see some other issue. Please give more details of the source image and the pixels sizes before and after resampling. What tool did you use for resampling?

Comment: @user30184 I have tried with the raster calculator, r.resample and r.resamp.stats. I have added more information about the files to the question. I am aware that not every extent would work, I'd be happy for the tool to "cut off" a bit at the edges to get to square pixels - but how do I tell it to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the GDAL [Warp (Reproject)](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html#gdalwarpreproject) tool and specify a resampling method and resolution:

[image]

As you are leaving the Source and Target CRS parameters empty, no reprojection is performed, just resampling.

For any future readers who want non-square pixels, you can use the additional command-line parameters to specify output pixel size using [`gdalwarp`'s](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) `-tr` parameter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!